# switch button doesnt appear as an item in OptionsMenu

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

i want to add a switch button as an item in options menu, preferably with its title beside him, like how the checkbox appears in the picture below

i tried this code for the menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/itemSwitch"
    android:title="Switch!"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item android:id="@+id/itemSettings"
    android:title="Settings"
   />
<item
    android:id="@+id/itemCheckable"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:title="im checkable" />
</menu>
```

and it looked like this:
[always showAsAction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Hl8.png)

but thats not what i want, i want it as an item of the menu. so i removed app:showAsAction="always" (or wrote app:showAsAction="never", it did the same) and then thats what happened:
[dont showAsAction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vy5o.png)

as u see now it doesnt show the switch but only its title. if i removed the title, it just turned blank.

is there a way to show a switch as an item of a menu at all? like just like the checkbox item - but with a switch instead.

thankss!

Comment: You add one menuitem,then click the menuitem pop a popmemu,and custom the layout of the popmenu.